# Definitely typed library support for Typescript 1.8.5

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2013, definitelytyped

I have searched for clues on how to work with Definitely typed libraries that  work with typescript 1.8 but haven't found anything helpful. My environment is Visual Studio 2013 with Typescript 1.8. Looks like most of the definitely typed libraries (backbone, requirejs, underscore, jquery among others) have moved into typescript 2.0 and above.

We have an existing app written in backbone with requirejs which we are trying to move to typescript. Not much help out there for that too.

Are there any Definitely typed libraries out there for typescript 1.8?

Should the typed libraries be included in the csproj file or should they be like nuget (not included but referenced)?

Can Definitely typed libraries written for typescript > 1.8 be used to work with 1.8 somehow?

Should I use nuget definitely typed libraries or should I use npm ones. If either then how cause nuget typed libraries definitely did not help and npm ones were (written for ts > 1.8) were throwing lots of errors?

Lastly, A big THANK YOU! to microsoft to ween the latest typescript versions off of visual studio 2013 for no good reason!

Thanks.

Comment: The version of TypeScript you are using does not matter, what you target with TSC does. Just upgrade your TypeScript to 2.0 or Above but don't change your target in your tsc.config and you will be fine.

Comment: @AdamH Thanks for replying. My mvc project is not reading from tsconfig.json which is placed at the root of the visual studio 2013 project. I have been configuring typescript with msbuild compiler options. You mean to say that I can install typescript 3.3.1 in visual studio 2013? this blog does not seem to agree with that - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11214

Comment: Huh I did not know that. If that is the case, and it looks like it is, then you either going to live without the support, upgrade VS or move the 'compiling' of the TypeScript outside of msbuild and use another editor. it sucks but i think those might be your only options.